# How to find $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, catalans-constant

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function whose restriction on $[-\pi, \pi]$ is $f(x)_{[-\pi, \pi]} = |x|$

It is easy to see that its fourier series converges uniformily to $f$ and is $$f(x) = \frac \pi2 - \frac 4\pi \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(2m+1)x}{(2m+1)^2}$$

Next it asks me three questions:

> Find $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac 1{(2m+1)^2}$

This is easy, just set $x=0$ to get at once $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac 1{(2m+1)^2} = \frac {\pi^2} 8$

> Find $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1)^4}$

Again, very easy. Using the parseval identity one gets $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1)^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{96}$

> Finally, find $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$$

This is where I am stuck. I thought about calculating the series in a suitable point $x$, but I can't get the cosine to behave like $(-1)^n$.
I tried writing it like $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{(2k+1)^2} - 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{(4k+3)^2}$$ but I don't know how to calculate the latter sum.

Hints are appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the series is known as [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). It's value is approximately 0.915 965 594. At the moment there is no known method to evaluate the series in closed form.

Comment: ah, I see. So I take it there is an error in the textbook?

Comment: Why an error? Perhaps they've the hope some student will find a nice, closed form for it.:)

Comment: @Timbuc Ahah well they've found the right guy! :P Thank you both :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)